# Why does .getComputedStyle() appear to be the only commonly used method to return the incorrect height of an element?

Tags: javascript, getcomputedstyle

**Question:** Under certain circumstances `.getComputedStyle()` appears to return an incomplete/incorrect value for the `height` property of an element.  Now I'm worried.  Is it known to return unpredictable or incorrect values for other properties?

**Backstory:** I had been using `.getComputedStyle()` until I noticed that it was returning what appeared to be incorrect values for the heights of elements.  So I tested it against several other methods.

In the simple test code below all of these returned 400 which is the correct height of the element that was tested.

`.offsetHeight`

`.scrollHeight`

`.clientHeight`

`.getBoundingClientRect().height`

However `.getComputedStyle().height` returned 300px which is the height of the element before its padding is applied.

```js
'use strict';
 
window.addEventListener('load', measureDiv)
 
function measureDiv() {
  console.log('offsetHeight = ' +document.querySelector('.container').offsetHeight);
  console.log('scrollHeight = ' +document.querySelector('.container').scrollHeight);
  console.log('clientHeight = ' +document.querySelector('.container').clientHeight);
  console.log('getBoundingClientRect().height = ' +document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().height);
  console.log('getComputedStyle().height = ' +window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.container')).height);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 
.container {
  margin: 120px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
 
.box_1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
 
.image_container {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="box_1">
   
    <div class="image_container"><img src="https://www.cis.rit.edu/~cnspci/courses/common/images/checkerboard-256x256.jpg"></div>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look incorrect to me; the `height` CSS property does not include the padding or the border unless you've got `box-sizing: border-box;` set.

Comment: @Pointy - Mind blown!  I just added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the class and sure enough it reported back 400px. I get it now.

Comment: @Pointy - FYI I just tested this with `box-sizing: border-box` in IE11 and it still reported a height of 300.14px.  But Chrome, Edge and Firefox all reported the correct height.

Comment: I'm not sure why IE would get that wrong; perhaps IE is running in one of its weird compatibility modes or quirks mode or something and that throws it off.

Comment: IE11 is down to 12.9% according to Analytics.gov https://analytics.usa.gov/  But that's down from just over 52% 2 years ago.  Hopefully it will be dead and buried in another 2 years.  I hate learning things in 2 ways.